# Can we carry electronic devices at the Swiss Regional Consular Centre, London?

Tags: electronic-items, consulates, swiss

At the Swiss Regional Consular Centre, London, are we allowed to carry electronic devices, like cellphones and laptops during a Visa interview?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I checked with the consulate security, They said we can carry them, but we cannot use them during the interview. However, you can use them when you are waiting in the lobby.

Comment: At a different London embassy that I'll have to visit soon, they tell you that if your phone rings during an interview, they will ask you to leave and make another appointment. So really make sure it's turned off.